# No error for @MainThread annotation

Tags: android, annotations

I have a method:

```
/**
 * Call event without a value
 */
@MainThread
public void call() {
    setValue(null);
}
```

And I call it here:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        stopNavigation.call();
    }
}).start();
```

Why is no error thrown because I am making this call from outside of the main thread? I have read everything I can about the `@MainThread` annotation (from `android.support.annotation`) but nothing has informed me on what the annotation actually does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, AndroidStudio only show the warning about thread when we specific all thread  like
[image]

Here is an example in `Activity` to make annotations work

```
public class AActivity extends Activity {

    @MainThread
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        getData();
    }

    @AnyThread
    private void getData() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @WorkerThread // MUST DEFINE THREAD HERE
            @Override
            public void run() {
                updateUI(); // annotation error here
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @MainThread
    void updateUI() {

    }

    class A extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @WorkerThread // MUST DEFINE THREAD HERE
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            updateUI(); // annotation error here
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```